# Why $\int{\log^2(2\sin(\pi x))}dx\neq\frac{\log^3(2\sin(\pi x))\sin(\pi x)}{3\pi \cos(\pi x)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

Apparently I completely forgot the basics of calculus after 13 years of not studying it. Why won't:

$$\frac{d \log^2(2\sin(\pi x))}{dx} = \frac{\log^3(2\sin(\pi x))\sin(\pi x)}{3\pi \cos(\pi x)}$$

---

UPDATE:

Sorry everybody, I messed up the question big time. Yes, originally it's an integration question why won't:

$$\int{\log^2(2\sin(\pi x))}dx = \frac{\log^3(2\sin(\pi x))\sin(\pi x)}{3\pi \cos(\pi x)}$$

Comment: What you wrote there seems to be akin to integration, NOT derivation: $\int t^2dt=\dfrac{t^3}3$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've since updated my question. It's incredibly hard these days to keep focusing on questions (luckily I'm already on a holiday).

Answer (score 3):

Using Chain rule:$$\frac{d }{dx}\log^2(2\sin(\pi x))=2\log(2\sin(\pi x))\times[2\times\pi\times\cos(\pi x)]\times\frac{1}{2\sin(\pi x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=2\sin(\pi x)$.

Then, 
$$\frac{d \log^2(f(x))}{dx}=2\log f(x)\times (\log f(x))^\prime.$$

Here, $$(\log f(x))^\prime=\frac{f^\prime (x)}{f(x)}=\frac{2\cos(\pi x)\times \pi}{2\sin(\pi x)}.$$

As a result, we have
$$\frac{d \log^2(f(x))}{dx}=2\log (2\sin(\pi x))\times \frac{2\cos(\pi x)\times \pi}{2\sin(\pi x)}.$$

If you feel any difficulty in my answer, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d \log^2(2\sin(\pi x))}{dx}=2\log (2\sin(\pi x))\frac{d \log(2\sin(\pi x))}{dx}=-2 \pi \log (2\sin(\pi x)) \cot( \pi x)$